# Formula that uses both vlookup and sumif for vertical summing

Tags: excel

I have two tabs in a spreadsheet. I have a vlookup to look at a cell in tab a and look up a corresponding number in tab b. But I need the result to sum vertically. For example in tab a with the formula I have the value 1310. In tab b I need the numbers corresponding to 1310 which are in the same column.

Tab A

Value    1310

Vlookup formula
1310     =VLOOKUP(A2,'TabB'!$1:$1048576,26,FALSE)

Tab B
Value

1310 5,601,000

1310 5,602,000

I want the formula in Tab A to sum both 1310's so in tab A I get 11,203,000

Is there a formula for this? I tried SUMIF with {} but I don't want a horizantal array I want a vertical one.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `SUMIF` no lookup is required:

```
=SUMIF(TabB!A:A,TabA!A2,TabB!B:B)
```

#### reference:

[SUMIF function](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/SUMIF-function-5fd078db-e5f8-4726-b08f-74fd0064e7fe?ui=en-US&rs=en-NZ&ad=NZ)

Answer (score 0):

SUMIF should work OK, e.g. If criteria is in column A and you want to sum column Z

> =SUMIF('TabB'!A:A,A2,'TabB'!Z:Z)